# How can I remove "User Defined Runtime Attributes" in Xcode and what are they?

Tags: ios, xcode, attributes, xcode5

In Xcode 5.0.2 I've created a new Master-Detail Application - and it worked well on iPhone and iPad simulators.

But then accidentally in **User Defined Runtime Attribites** in the right panel of Xcode I've clicked (three times) a plus and added "keyPath" entries (without really understanding what they are):

[image]

How can I remove them please? Clicking a minus doesn't change anything and running in simulator now fails with:

```
2013-11-24 21:02:53.003 MDExample[23132:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableView 0xab26000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bf8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017cc6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x011809ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x010eccfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x010ec253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   UIKit                               0x00297e0b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    7   Foundation                          0x0114e70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    8   UIKit                               0x007aa0c5 -[UINibKeyValuePair apply] + 70
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d17d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x01737b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    11  UIKit                               0x004ce552 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1389
    12  UIKit                               0x00340605 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    13  UIKit                               0x00340dad -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    14  UIKit                               0x004e911e -[UITableViewController loadView] + 80
    15  UIKit                               0x003410ae -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
    16  UIKit                               0x003415b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    17  UIKit                               0x0036bca9 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
    18  UIKit                               0x00695a60 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
    19  UIKit                               0x002712f2 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
    20  UIKit                               0x00270d16 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    21  UIKit                               0x00270be8 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    22  UIKit                               0x00270c70 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    23  UIKit                               0x0026fd0a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    24  UIKit                               0x0026fc6c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    25  UIKit                               0x002709c3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    26  UIKit                               0x00273fb6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    27  UIKit                               0x00345737 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    28  UIKit                               0x00269c1c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 609
    29  UIKit                               0x00269d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    30  UIKit                               0x0026a02d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    31  UIKit                               0x0027489a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    32  UIKit                               0x00227cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    33  UIKit                               0x0022c3a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    34  UIKit                               0x0024087c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    35  UIKit                               0x00240de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    36  UIKit                               0x0022e025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x036932f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x03692e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x016e277c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x016e1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x016e18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    44  UIKit                               0x0022badd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    45  UIKit                               0x0022dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    46  MDExample                           0x00003b3d main + 141
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d78725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Selecting one of the entries and clicking the minus doesn't do anything? File a bug on that for sure.

Comment: Wait -- _did_ you **select** the entry before trying to remove it? That works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Defined Runtime Attributes are just that: User defined keypaths that may not be available in the standard interface builder editor for a given class/control.  When you click to add one, you instruct the NIB defroster to call `setValue:forKey:`, in this case with the keypath `keyPath` and the value `NO` (or rather, `@NO`).  Naturally, as `UITableView` has no keypath or property named `keyPath`, the KVC mechanism will crash.

To remove one, it must be highlighted, then either the delete key or the "minus button" will work:

[image]

If the problem persists, [file a bug report](http://www.bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: What is a `@NO` please? I only know `NO` sofar - which is similar to `FALSE` in other languages

Comment: It's an NSNumber literal.  KVC only deals with objects, and boxes scalars where appropriate.

Comment: @ followed by a value that fits in an NSNumber is "syntax sugar" -- a shortcut for typing `[NSNumber numberWith*type*: foo];`  So, for example: `@YES, @(YES), @17, @(100+sqrt(3))`, translates to `...numberWithBool: YES` (2x), `...numberWithInt: 17` and `numberWithFloat: 101.73205080756888`